# What does 'teach' mean in 'teach a seminar'?

Tags: meaning

> She is **teaching** a seminar.

In this sentence, Can I regard '**teach**' as '**lead**'?

as in:

> She is **leading** a seminar.

Comment: I'd say usually you "give" a seminar. If someone is teaching a seminar I'd imagine they're giving a seminar in which they are teaching something. Or leading a seminar, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the seminar.  If the seminar is at a conference or meeting
I would think that the one "teaching" the seminar may be someone presenting or running the seminar.   However I recall that in some universities they have courses (perhaps expected to be attended by relatively few people, an experimental course, etc.) that are referred to as "seminars" and the one "teaching the seminar" is the one lecturing.

Answer (score 0):

> She is teaching a seminar.

is surely not the best way to transmit that information. It would be significantly better to say:

> She is teaching (the ABC science / discipline / method / ...) a seminar.

as in:

> She is teaching *leadership* at a seminar.

Your attempt to say "teach = lead" in this context, is only partially correct. If the seminar is ONLY about leadership, and nobody else is involved in organizing and running the seminar, then the same person does both jobs: teaching and leading.

But there may be a different case: a seminar may have several "classes": leadership, team building, conflict management, escalation procedure... And each class may have different teachers. At the same time, the entire event might be organized and coordinated by a person who does not teach anything. In this case, there are some persons who **teach** and a person who **leads**. Therefore, in this case "teach" and "lead" are not interchangeable.

If you take it a little to the extreme, you may say that each teacher "leads" their own class, but I think that it is not very clear to everybody what you mean, in this case.